# c# getting a string from textbox using get set , than sending it another class?

Tags: c#, class, textbox, get, set

I have a homework that i should make an accounting application with user login.My problem is , i have to use {get,set} but i don't know how to use them properly.there is one class called 'UserLogin.cs' and one form 'UserLoginForm.cs'.In userLoginForm there is two maskedTextBoxes :
maskedTextBoxID and maskedTextBoxPass.

When i click login button on userLoginForm, it calls a function from userloginclass to check if id and pass are correct or not?

The problem is when i click the login button, the id and pass coming from maskedTextBoxes is not that i entered before click login , they are always maskedTextBoxes's first value : empty...

if i enter 123 as id and 123 as pass then if i check them in function to if id is "123" and pass is "123",, there is wrong id&pass message occurs.

this time:if i enter 123 as id and 123 as pass , then if check them in function to if id is " " and pass is " " (which is their first value) the login is sucsesful.

where is the problem?

in userlogin form

```
    public partial class UserLoginForm : Form
{
    public UserLoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string userID
    {
        get
        {
            return maskedTextBoxID.Text;
        }
    }

    public string userPASS
    {
        get
        {
            return maskedTextBoxPass.Text;
        }
    }


    private void button_enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserLogin ulogcs = new UserLogin();
        ulogcs.checklogin();
```

in user login class:

```
    public void checklogin()
    {
        UserLoginForm uform = new UserLoginForm();
        if (uform.userID == "123" && uform.userPASS == "123")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the bank");
            AccountForm aform = new AccountForm();
            aform.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

sorry for grammar (i am not native speaker)

Comment: Make an instance of the login class and pass the info to it. Or make the checklogin method(which should accept two string arguments) static and just invoke it directly.

Comment: In `checklogin()`, `UserLoginForm uform = new UserLoginForm();` creates a new form. I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: i send string to checklogin() function as you and other comments say ,and my problem is solved.thank you for help and extra information about creating new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Because you are instantiating a new `UserLoginForm` object in your "UserLogin" class, it starts with default data (the empty strings) *not* the data your user entered.

The quickest fix is to just pass the form:

```
private void button_enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserLogin ulogcs = new UserLogin(this);
    ulogcs.checklogin();
```

in user login class:

```
private UserLoginForm uform;

public UserLogin(UserLoginForm loginForm)
{
   uform = loginForm;
}

public void checklogin()
{       
    if (uform.userID == "123" && uform.userPASS == "123")
    ...
}
```

In this code, we use the `this` keyword to get a reference to the current object (the form itself) and pass it to a parameterized constructor of the UserLogin class. It stores this off to get the data later when we call `checklogin`.

Better would to just pass the data:

```
private void button_enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserLogin ulogcs = new UserLogin();
    ulogcs.checklogin(userID, userPASS);
```

in user login class:

```
public void checklogin(string user, string password)
{       
    if (user == "123" && password == "123")
    ...
}
```

In this code we recognize that `userlogin` shouldn't care where the data comes from, it just needs the data. Thus, we change the signature of `checklogin` to accept the username and password and just use them. No reference to the form (or knowledge that it even exists) is required.

Comment: i send string to checklogin() function as you and other comments say ,and my problem is solved.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the definition of this function

```
 public void checklogin()
    {
        UserLoginForm uform = new UserLoginForm();
        if (uform.userID == "123" && uform.userPASS == "123")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the bank");
            AccountForm aform = new AccountForm();
            aform.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

to

```
 public void checklogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        if (user== "123" && pass == "123")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the bank");
            AccountForm aform = new AccountForm();
            aform.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

and call it

```
 ulogcs.checklogin(uform.userID,uform.userPASS);
```

you dont need to create this

```
UserLoginForm uform = new UserLoginForm();
```

as this will create new form and this will not contain your entered values

Comment: i send string to checklogin() function as you and other comments say ,and my problem is solved.thank you for help and extra information about creating new form.